# Css effect not working properly to @Html.actionlink in mvc

Tags: css, model-view-controller

Actionlink:

```
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit","City",new { id = item.CityID},new {@class= "PoPrint" })




    Here is the Style I am applying:




        <style>
         PoPrint {
                border: 4px outset;
                padding: 2px;
                text-decoration: none;
                background-color: lightskyblue;
            }
        </style>
```

I have @Html.ActionLink that I want to make look like buttons.i am assigning the css to my actionlink but css effect is not occuring to my actionlik.
i use @class to apply css but still not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put a dot before your class name, replace `PoPrint` with `.PoPrint`

```
<style>
.PoPrint { //you should put a dot before the classname
    border: 4px outset;
    padding: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: lightskyblue;
}
</style>
```